# Uploading data into Google spreadsheet from android app

Tags: android, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am building an android app in which I was just thinking can I update required data directly on Google Drive. That is I will be having a Spread Sheet in my Google Drive so the data which I require I will upload into that sheet. Is this possible? And If yes which Api for android should I use and is there any sample for the same.